# Upload from Mathematica to YouTube

Tags: web-access, video

I'd like to take some little videos I made in Mathematica and put them on YouTube. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 30):

I built a service connection for this and blogged about it here: [Playing with YouTube from Mathematica](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/playing-with-youtube-from-mathematica.html#main-content)

Here's an example of how this works.

#### Connect to YouTube

First install the paclet:

```
PacletInstall["ServiceConnection_YouTube",
  "Site"->
    "http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer/"
  ]
```

[image: post22-8529256040837869960]
<sub>(source: [wolframcloud.com](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/img/post22-8529256040837869960.png))</sub>

Then connect:

```
$so = ServiceConnect["YouTube"]
```

[image: post22-6049558537553480280]
<sub>(source: [wolframcloud.com](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/img/post22-6049558537553480280.png))</sub>

#### Upload Video

```
anim =
  Export[
    FileNameJoin@{$TemporaryDirectory, "plot3d.flv"},
    Manipulate[
      Plot3D[Sin[n x y], 
        {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
        ViewPoint -> Dynamic[{2, v, 2}], SphericalRegion -> True, Ticks -> None,
        PerformanceGoal->"Quality"
        ], 
      {n, 1, 4}, 
      {v, -2, 2}
      ]
    ];

upload = $so["UploadVideo", "part"->"id", "BodyContent"->anim];
```

#### Add Metadata

Because of how I built it you have to add the metadata after the upload. You do it like this:

```
$so["UpdateVideo", "id" -> upload["id"],
 "part" -> "snippet",
  "Title" -> "Mathematica Examples: Plot 3D",
 "CategoryID" -> "22"
 ]
```

#### Get an IFrame for Embedding

```
$so["EmbedIFrame", "id"->upload["id"]]

<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Quzcr4Vuq_Q?autoplay=0"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Here's the raw URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch/?v=Quzcr4Vuq_Q